# mediaelement in windowsphone8.1 stop working

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I'm using mediaelement in my windows phone 8.1 app. I have some others button too. When I use buttons it's a link to a website. When I use back button to back to my mainpage the mediaelement stop working. What can I do?

```
//this is my media element in xaml
<MediaElement x:Name="nima" Source="assets/jadid.mp3" AutoPlay="True"/>
```

I even use:

```
private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    nima.Play();
}
```

But it's not working. Please help me.

Comment: Formatting description and code.

Comment: its a mp3 audio, i want it to play in my app background but when i use back button my audio stopped playing

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play audio when your application is not in the foreground then you need to create a Background Audio Task and include that inside your solution.

See [MSDN: Background Audio for Windows Phone 8.1 Sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/BackgroundAudio-63bbc319) for complete tutorial and project files.